# Javascript 3 x 3 flexbox with button increasing number

Tags: javascript

I have a box **2 x 2** using flex property with number **0** inside each box, and a button to click

```js
function click() {
    var id = "item-";;
    for(var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
      id = id + i;
      var element = document.getElementById(id);
      var value = element.innerHTML;
      value++;
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
    }     
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="container-1">
    <div id="item-1">0</div>
    <div id="item-2">0</div>
    <div id="item-3">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-2">
    <div id="item-4">0</div>
    <div id="item-5">0</div>
    <div id="item-6">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn" onclick="click()">Click</button>
```

I want to create a function **click()** that if I click a button then the number inside the box will increase, but not all numbers in all boxes. I want the number increasing box by box.

But my function only increases the value in the first box. Can someone let me know what should I do, please?

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: Also, there is no element with `id` with just a number. You're not doing anything with the `item-` part

Comment: @0stone0 that's a typo in the line var i = 0. It should be var id = "item-". It only works with the first box

Comment: I've moved your code into a runnable snippet. The onclick does not match the function name so nothing happens when you press the button

Comment: Yea the name of the function should be click(). But it also didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, first iteration of the `for ()` will work because `id` will become `item-1`, but the second iteration you will create the new `id`, but you just append `i`, so it becomes `item-12` instead of `item-2`

Just only remember the `id` and prefix it with `item-` when you use it. Then after each press, update the `innerHTML` and increase the counter, or reset to `1` if we've just updated the last `<div>`

```js
var currentIndex = 1;

function incrementButton() {
    let element = document.getElementById('item-' + currentIndex);
    element.innerHTML = ++element.innerHTML;
     
    currentIndex = (currentIndex === 6) ? 1 : ++currentIndex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="container-1">
    <div id="item-1">0</div>
    <div id="item-2">0</div>
    <div id="item-3">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-2">
    <div id="item-4">0</div>
    <div id="item-5">0</div>
    <div id="item-6">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn" onclick="incrementButton()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Actually, I don't want all the numbers increasing after clicking a button. I want a one-number increase in one click, then the next number increase in the next click. I

Comment: Ah, didn't get that. Please see my edit.

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much for your answer. It works now
However, if I add some css like .flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
.item {
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

Then is there someway that I can increase the number from left to right then top to bottom instead of top to bottom then left to right?